# Program Broken, Not sure why variables are wrong

Tags: c#

I need help with a class assignment, I use try-catch at first but now he wants me to try and do the error checking without try-catch. I had it working and then he also wanted me to use a method for the math that had executing twice and have now broken my program and I'm not sure why.

The program is supposed to take two numbers, and then display the sum, quotient, product, and difference. But as far as I can tell the math is being done with random numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TeamStuff
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double one = 2, two = 1;
            string check = null;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number 1: ");
                check = Console.ReadLine();

                if (CheckParse(check, one) == true)
                {
                    one = Convert.ToDouble(check);
                    break;
                }

            }

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number 2: ");
                check = Console.ReadLine();

                if (CheckParse(check, two) == true)
                {
                    two = Convert.ToDouble(check);
                    if (two == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You cannot divide by zero, try again.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    one = Convert.ToDouble(check);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Sum=" + (one + two) +
                "\nProduct= " + (one * two) +
                "\nDifference= " + (one-two) +
                "\nQuotient= " + (one/two)
                );

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static Boolean CheckParse(string x, double y)
        {
            return double.TryParse(x, out y);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Please explain exactly what your issue is.

Comment: Try again, provide your inputs and the outputs that you see. Don't count on us to just magically compile and run the code in our heads :)

Comment: In your second while loop, it looks like you're assigning the input to variable `one` instead of `two` in the `else` clause. You should probably remove that line...(using my in-head compiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                two = Convert.ToDouble(check);
                if (two == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You cannot divide by zero, try again.");
                }
                else
                {
                one = Convert.ToDouble(check);
                    break;
                }
```

This should be

```
                two = Convert.ToDouble(check);
                if (two == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You cannot divide by zero, try again.");
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
```

On another note, you don't need to convert twice, you can pass a value by reference by boxing it.

```
    // Notice the out keyword ---------\  /
    //                                  \/
    static Boolean CheckParse(string x, out double y)
    {
        // out keyword-----------\  /
        //                        \/
        return double.TryParse(x, out y);
    }
```

Have a look at:

- [C# Beginners Tutorial - 153 - Ref and Out Keywords](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcouA7mu2aQ)
- [MSDN - Output Parameters](http://Output%20parameters)